# How to pass variables into SQLite in java

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to create a SQLite for my game, and its working fine until I try to put some variables in the table HighScores.
If I try to put a variable it only works if I delete the "NOT NULL".

```
public void SQLite(){
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");

        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE HighScores " +
                "(ID INT PRIMARY KEY        NOT NULL," +
                " POINTS         INT        NOT NULL, " + 
                " NAME           CHAR(50)   NOT NULL, " + 
                " TIME           INT        NOT NULL, " + 
                " LEVEL          INT        NOT NULL)"; 
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);


        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql2 = "INSERT INTO HIGHSCORES (ID,POINTS,NAME,TIME,LEVEL) " +
                "VALUES (1, ?, 'rodrigo', 99, 1 );";
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql2);
        ps.setInt(1, 5);

        stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);

        stmt.close();
        c.commit();
        c.close();

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Opened database successfully.
java.sql.SQLException: NOT NULL constraint failed: HighScores.POINTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `executeUpdate` on `stmt` instead of the prepared statement. Since `sql2` does not have any value for `POINTS`, it try to insert null hence the exception.

Change :

```
stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);
```

to

```
ps.executeUpdate();
```